# Java call methods using ||

Tags: java

This is the line I have trouble understanding

```
return (match(regex.substring(1), s)|| match(regex, s.substring(1)));
```

My understanding is that it would call the latter if the first method is false. So I wrote an simple program to test.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   System.out.println(test(5));
}

public static boolean test(int a)
{
    System.out.println(a);
    if (a>10)
        return true;
    if (a==4)
        return false;
    else
        return (test(a-1) || (test(a+1)));
}
```

But it just prints 5 4 6 5 4 6...

Comment: list of java operators: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A logical OR is true if either the left or the right expression is true.  If the left expression is true, a computer language can opt not to evaluate the right expression to save time.  That is, in fact, exactly what Java does.

That means that

```
match(regex, s.substring(1))
```

will be executed if and only if

```
match(regex.substring(1), s)
```

is false.

So the return value is:

- *true* if `match(regex.substring(1), s)` returns true,
- the return value of `match(regex, s.substring(1)` otherwise

Comment: Could you take a look at the simple program I added? I'm not sure where went wrong.

Comment: Your new program should eventually return *true*.  On the first call with 5, it calls itself recursively, first with 5-1=4 (returns false), then since left side of || is false, with 5+1=6.  It will keep going until the right-hand operand is > 10, at which point the iteration will terminate, returning true.  Is that not what you expect?  Is that not what you get?

Comment: I got Stackoverflow error. But if I set the first if condition to a ==6 it will return true

Answer (score 0):

It's equivalent to:

```
if match(regex.substring(1), s) return true;
if match(regex, s.substring(1)) return true;
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The program you wrote calls test with a 5 as a param. This prints the five. This is not bigger than 10 of 4, so it goes to the else. In the else you call it's own method recursively, with a 4 the first time. So the 4 is printed This returns a false. Then it tries the second which is a+1, so it calls test with a 6. This prints the 6 on the screen, falls through to the else, and calls test again recursively, with a (which is now 6) -1 so with a 5. This loop is endless.

You have to put the first if:
    if (a==4)

This fixes the program, but not what you want to get.

Also the problem is that you use the logical or completely wrong. An OR is meant to see if one of the both answers is true. If you want to call a method depending on a situation, you have to use an if or a ternary operator.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   System.out.println(test(5));
}

public static boolean test(int a)
{
    System.out.println(a);
    if (a>10)
        return true;
    if (a==4)
        return false;
    else
        if(test(a-1)) {
            return test(a-1);
        }
        else {
            return (test(a+1));
        }
}
```

This should give you what you want I guess